# How to calculate sum of total items in the RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to calculate sum of all items and display them in a toast, how can I calculate them?

[image]

That's My onBindViewHolder

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder_chart viewHolder_chart, int i) {

    viewHolder_chart.p_name_CHART_tv.setText(_chartdata.get(i).getName_prdct()); // set name of product
    //Replace these two methods
    viewHolder_chart.p_price_CHART_tv.setText(_chartdata.get(i).getPrice_prdct());  // set quantity
    viewHolder_chart.p_quantity_Chart_tv.setText(_chartdata.get(i).getUnit_prdct());  // set price
    ////////////////////////////////
    viewHolder_chart.p_totalITem_CHART_tv.setText(_chartdata.get(i).getTotal_quantity());

    Log.d("Adapter_chart","bitmap="+_chartdata.get(i).getImage_prdct());
    viewHolder_chart.p_img_CHART.setImageBitmap(_chartdata.get(i).getImage_prdct());



    total += _chartdata.get(i).getPrice_prdct();

    if(i==_chartdata.size()-1){//check if list last element
        //show your total count view here---- and add total amount

        Toast.makeText(context, "t="+total, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: what you have tried?, please post your adapter

Comment: i want to calculate only sum of these values.

Comment: i know what you are asking for but i have to know which view you are using to display quantity and which model you are using etc. thats why i'm asking for recyclerview adapter

Comment: onBindViewHolder is posted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove below line from onBindViewHolder:

```
 total += _chartdata.get(i).getPrice_prdct();
```

because onBindViewHolder will call every time you scroll and try to restore position with view, so we can't do this type of things here like sum of product or quantity or etc.,

```
public int getMyTotalQuantity(){
    int totalQuantity = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<_chartdata.size(); i++){
        if(_chartdata.get(i) != null && _chartdata.get(i).getTotal_quantity() != null &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(_chartdata.get(i).getTotal_quantity())){
        totalQuantity = totalQuantity + Integer.parseInt(_chartdata.get(i).getTotal_quantity());
    }
    return totalQuantity;
}
```

If you want to show the view at last with sum of quantity then you can declare method as above and then use it in onBindViewHolder as below:

```
if(i==_chartdata.size()-1){//check if list last element

        // to get total quantity
        Toast.makeText(context, "total quantity = " + getMyTotalQuantity(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

You can create same method to get the sum of amount and use it in bind view holder.

Comment: Thanx! this is really working, you saved my lot of time

Comment: Hey, help me!!!   this solution really working but there is little problem, when i'm trying to set this final value in my textview then value is not set first time ,when i move from another fragment to this fragment second time then value is set on my textview.

Comment: And also there is another problem, when i remove any item from my recyclerview then this value should be update, how is it possible?